# Python how to make a Thread run infinite times with a loop

Tags: python, multithreading

Hello everyone I got a project assigned to me where I have to simulate a car parking garage with LED's and ultra sonic sensor's where I have to detect if the parking spot is full or not. Now I have to use threads to run multiple ultrasonic's at the same time. I have a code that works for one ultrasonic sensor but when I try to implement threads I keep getting the error

```
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once
```

Because my code looks something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = Thread(target=main_function)
    while True:
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
```

Here is my full code:

```
from threading import Thread
import threading
from rpi_lcd import LCD
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

TRIG_1 = 21
ECHO_1 = 20
TRIG = 23   
ECHO = 24
LED_RED = 17
LED_GREEN = 22
LED_RED1 = 26
LED_GREEN1 = 19


lcd = LCD()
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(TRIG, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(TRIG_1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(ECHO_1, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(LED_GREEN,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(LED_RED,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(LED_GREEN1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(LED_RED1,GPIO.OUT)

def main_function():
    try:

        GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
        GPIO.output(TRIG_1, False)
        time.sleep(2)
        GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
        GPIO.output(TRIG_1, True)
        time.sleep(0.00001)
        GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
        GPIO.output(TRIG_1, False)

        while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:
            pulse_start = time.time()

        while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
            pulse_end = time.time()
        
        pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
        distance = pulse_duration * 17150
        distance = round(distance, 1)
        
        if distance >= 20:
            GPIO.output(LED_GREEN, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(LED_GREEN1, GPIO.HIGH)
            # GPIO.output(LED_RED1, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(LED_RED, GPIO.LOW) 
            GPIO.output(LED_RED1, GPIO.LOW) 
            
        else:
            GPIO.output(LED_GREEN, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(LED_RED, GPIO.HIGH) 

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Cleaning up!")
        GPIO.cleanup
        GPIO.output(LED_GREEN,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(LED_RED, GPIO.LOW)  
        GPIO.output(LED_GREEN1,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(LED_RED1, GPIO.LOW)  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                             
if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = Thread(target=main_function)
    while True:
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
```

I Looked on the internet and it says that I can't keep re-running the `thread.start()` function. I don't know what other option I have to do this, can someone help me with this. if you need more information let me know.

This is how my code structure is gonna look like

```
#Changed def main_function to PK_1
def PK_1():
  # some code that has to do with 1 ultrasonic and 2 leds

def PK_2():
  # some code that has to do with another 1 ultrasonic and 2 leds

def PK_3():
  # some code that has to do with another 1 ultrasonic and 2 leds

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = Thread(target=PK_1)
    thread1 = Thread(target=PK_2)
    thread2 = Thread(target=PK_3)
    while True:
        thread.start()
        thread1.start()
        thread2.start()
        thread.join()
        thread1.join()
        thread2.join()
```

Comment: try moving the loop inside your ```main_function()```

Comment: Yes, why not just: `while True: main_function()`?

Comment: @JonSG how would that work if I add a second function `Thread2`? will it be reachable because the first thread is still in a loop?

Comment: @quamrana how would that work if I add a second function Thread2? will it be reachable because the first thread is still in a loop?

Comment: Please update your question with your real requirements. How many threads do you want?

Comment: @quamrana I have updated the question to what my (end) goal is

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run three threads, then you have to do just that. This is a pattern to follow:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    targets = [PK_1, PK_2, PK_3]
    threads = [Thread(target=t) for t in targets]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

The only extra thing is to make sure each target will loop until it needs to stop.